# What is the difference between a kernel and a filter?

Tags: filter, imageprocessing

What is the difference between a kernel and a filter? (Not for CNN, in general.)

Comment: Kernel is the matrix a *digital* filter is using to calculate the result (the matrix which is convolved with the source data).

Comment: What I understand is filter is a more general terms including kernel, because filter can be a matrix, too. Is it correct?

Comment: Filter is a thing that is working by applying the kernel. The difference is as between a painter and a paint. Painter is not more general than paint. It's just a different thing.

Comment: For image processing: A filter would be the result of using a kernel (or masking). CNN's use, surprise surprise, _convolution_ but that's an entirely different algorithm since there are weights and activation functions, etc.

Comment: A filter is more of a general transfer function or model concept, while a kernel has a specific and unique realization (ex. gaussian kernel, Laplacian, etc.). Kernels are different models to realize filters, but not the other way around.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Kernels can have any dimensionality, and can either be discrete or continuous.  I was originally introduced to the concept in a detection & estimation class where it was all 1D, or, if multidimensional, it was a finite-length vector of measurements evolving over a potentially infinite span of time.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is a matrix of numbers. It doesn't *do* anything, it's just data.

The filter uses the kernel data to actually *do* the filtering. It uses data in the kernel to perform convolutions.

I suppose the two terms could be confounded, since the behaviour of the filter depends entirely on the kernel, and you would design the kernel depending on how you want the filter to behave.

However, that's like saying a carpenter is the tools he uses, or the tools are the carpenter.

Answer (score 0):

A kernel is the 2 dimensional matrix for 2d convolution (or 1d also), A kernel defines the size of the convolution. A filter is the values stored in the kernel matrix. A kernel matrix doesn't have to be a filter, for example if you had a kernel with

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

the kernal above wouldn't filter anything, but leave you with what you started after convolution.

You can also make edge detectors, like the one below
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\1&0&-1\\1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}

Comment: *A filter is the values stored in the kernel matrix* - this doesn't sound right.

Comment: You don't have to build a filter with a kernel matrix,

Comment: The kernel is the thing that stores the values for convolution.

Comment: You don't, but it doesn't make filter to be *the values* of the matrix. Kernel is a property of a filter, not vice versa

Comment: In image processing, a kernel, convolution matrix, or mask is a small matrix. -wikipedia

Comment: I do not disagree with that. I disagree that *A filter is the values stored in the kernel matrix*

Comment: If you have an opamp with unity gain is it a filter? Probably not, if you have a kernel with a gain of 1, is it a filter?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to values being filter, but my answer is yes, it can be considered a filter depending on the context.